# Plot Pandas DataFrame as Bar and Line on the same one chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a chart with the 1st and 2nd columns of data as bars and then a line overlay for the 3rd column of data.

I have tried the following code but this creates 2 separate charts but I would like this all on one chart.

```py
left_2013 = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'],
                     '2013_val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 6]})

right_2014 = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['jan', 'feb'], '2014_val': [4, 5]})

right_2014_target = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'],
                                   '2014_target_val': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]})


df_13_14 = pd.merge(left_2013, right_2014, how='outer')
df_13_14_target = pd.merge(df_13_14, right_2014_target, how='outer')
df_13_14_target[['month','2013_val','2014_val','2014_target_val']].head(12)

plt.figure()
df_13_14_target[['month','2014_target_val']].plot(x='month',linestyle='-', marker='o')
df_13_14_target[['month','2013_val','2014_val']].plot(x='month', kind='bar')
```

This is what I currently get

[image: kpi dashboard]

Comment: I managed to get this working with the following code


       fig, ax = plt.subplots()
         df_13_14_target[['month','2014_target_val']].plot(x='month',ax=ax, linestyle='--', marker='o', color='r')
       df_13_14_target[['month','2013_val','2014_val']].plot(x='month',ax=ax, kind='bar')

However any ideas on how to make the line plots centerd above the bars

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The DataFrame plotting methods return a matplotlib `AxesSubplot` or list of `AxesSubplots`. (See [the docs for plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), or [boxplot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html), for instance.)

You can then pass that same Axes to the next plotting method (using `ax=ax`) to draw on the same axes:

```
ax = df_13_14_target[['month','2014_target_val']].plot(x='month',linestyle='-', marker='o')
df_13_14_target[['month','2013_val','2014_val']].plot(x='month', kind='bar', 
   ax=ax)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

left_2013 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'month': ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep',
               'oct', 'nov', 'dec'],
     '2013_val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 6]})

right_2014 = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['jan', 'feb'], '2014_val': [4, 5]})

right_2014_target = pd.DataFrame(
    {'month': ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep',
               'oct', 'nov', 'dec'],
     '2014_target_val': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]})

df_13_14 = pd.merge(left_2013, right_2014, how='outer')
df_13_14_target = pd.merge(df_13_14, right_2014_target, how='outer')

ax = df_13_14_target[['month', '2014_target_val']].plot(
    x='month', linestyle='-', marker='o')
df_13_14_target[['month', '2013_val', '2014_val']].plot(x='month', kind='bar',
                                                        ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is with the index. By default the plot method sets ```use_index=True``` to define x axis tick labels. Try setting ```use_index=False``` and you will get the expected results. [API here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Comment: is there a way we can set a different axis for the line ? Say it has normalised values, I'd want to show another y axis to the right, with limits (0, 1) and have the line follow that axis

Comment: `use_index=False` can be dangerous if your index values aren't identical between series...

Comment: This is cool, though it doesn't work if the index is a DateTime, say if you add `df_13_14_target['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df_13_14_target['month'], format='%b')` before plotting.

Answer (score 1):

To plot two plots on the same `axes`, `ax=` should be the same. It's true even if you use data from different frames.

```py
ax = right_2014.plot(x='month', kind='bar', color='r')
left_2013.plot(x='month', kind='bar', color='b', ax=ax);
```

**Small note**: The line plot can be plotted without passing `x=` because if it's not passed, the index will be used as the ticks (which can be overwritten by `month` in the second `plot()` call).

This method is particularly useful if `month` is a datetime column because using datetime values are messing up the ticks when the values themselves are not important here (it's only relevant as ticklabels).

```py
ax = df.plot(y='2014_target_val', linestyle='-', marker='o')
df.plot(x='month', y=['2013_val', '2014_val'], kind='bar', ax=ax);
```

If the index were datetime, then don't use index as ticks (via `use_index=False`) but use it as the ticks in the second `plot()` call:

```py
ax = df.plot(y='2014_target_val', linestyle='-', marker='o', use_index=False)
df.plot(y=['2013_val', '2014_val'], kind='bar', ax=ax);
```

[image: res]

**A working example:**

```py
# sample
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'], 
    '2013_val': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 9, 6], 
    '2014_val': [4.0, 5.0, *[float('nan')]*10], 
    '2014_target_val': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]})

# month data to datetime
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%b')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, facecolor='white')
df.plot(y='2014_target_val', linestyle='-', marker='o', ax=ax)
df.plot(x='month', y=['2013_val', '2014_val'], kind='bar', ax=ax)

# convert the tick labels (month names) into readable format
ax.set(xticklabels=pd.to_datetime([dt.get_text() for dt in ax.get_xticklabels()]).strftime('%b'));
```