# Combine Bar and line plots in one chart for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have similar problem as this question through this link[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482201/plot-pandas-dataframe-as-bar-and-line-on-the-same-one-chart/), but I tried to follow many times and it did not work for my case. So, please kindly help me.

I have the table/data as below and would like to plot column Guideline as Line plot and the rest of the column as Bar plot into one chart without secondary_y.

May data:

Year    Guidline    LMX LPB LVT LBF LBH LSD LKL LDN
2007    100 50  50  160 222 473 1,408   17  194
2008    200 47  231 17  508 19  278 219 1,707
2011    300 31  42  29  56  27  102 40  145
2013    500 11.7    9   8   10  17  30  5   14
2015    22.33   50  90  150 178 82  159 86  226

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_excel('F:/MRCS_New_struture/2. EHM_Vanna/2015 Reports/Statistic_Env.xlsx', sheetname='Zooplankton (3)', header=0, index_col='Year')

Guideline=df.iloc[:5,:1]
LaoAB=df.iloc[:5,1:9]

plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplots()

Guideline.plot(ax=ax)
LaoAB.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Please kindly help me. Many thanks

Comment: And what is wrong with your code? Do you get an error? Separate plots? Something else? You have told us what you are trying to achieve, but not where you are stuck. In any case, just because you haven't been able to get the solution working for you doesn't mean this is not a duplicate of the question you linked to.

Comment: @SiHa, yes I get a separate plots. I want both plots combined together in one chart. Could please kindly help?