# How to plot date range with vlines in matplotlib?

Tags: date, matplotlib, plot

The answer to this question appears relevant to my problem, however, it applies for ax.bar() instead of ax.vlines.

[Matplotlib DateFormatter for axis label not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743394/matplotlib-dateformatter-for-axis-label-not-working)

The code below works with ax1.vlines(x, l, h, colors='k') and ax2.vlines(x, 0, v, colors='k') to plot vertical price and volume bars in a stock chart. But the horizontal axis is defined by a numpy array x = 0,1,2,3, ... etc. I have datetime objects in array *d* but if change to ax1.vlines(d, l, h, colors='k') and ax2.vlines(d,0,v,colors='k') then it throws an error. Thus *d* is defined but not used in the code below (it won't work using *d* but it works using *x* in the referenced code lines).

```
    import datetime
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df = pd.read_csv(PATH+ticker+EXT, usecols=[0,2,3,4,5], header=None,
                     engine='python',skiprows=skr,skipfooter=skf)
    d = pd.to_datetime(df[0]) # numpy array date
    h = df[2].values # numpy array high
    l = df[3].values # numpy array low
    c = df[4].values # numpy array close
    v = df[5].values # numpy array volume
    x = np.arange(len(d))
    # Draw Chart to White Background        
    ax1_y_label = ticker
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    fig1.set_size_inches(WIDE,TALL)
    fig1.set_dpi(DTPI)
    fig1.autofmt_xdate()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((5,4), (0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=4)
    ax1.set_ylabel(ax1_y_label)
    ax1.grid(True)
    ax1.vlines(x, l, h, colors='k')
    ax1.hlines(c, x, x+0.3, color='k')
    ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((5,4), (4,0), sharex=ax1, rowspan=1, colspan=4)
    ax2.set_ylabel(ax2_y_label)
    ax2.grid(True)
    ax2.vlines(x, 0, v, colors='k')
    ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(ax1.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.01)
```

Comment: If you could provide a [MCVE], people might be more willing to help you find a solution. In your code it's not even clear where `d` is used and what the problem is.