# Change date x-axis from day to month in grouped bar plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, pandas-groupby, date-formatting

I am trying to change my x-axis ticks from day to month in my grouped bar plot. I tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968985/changing-the-formatting-of-a-datetime-axis-in-matplotlib) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743394/matplotlib-dateformatter-for-axis-label-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33743394/matplotlib-dateformatter-for-axis-label-not-working) but none of them worked. 
My code to display the plot with daily ticks which works is the following:

```
ax = data.groupby(['pos', data['date'].dt.strftime('')])['date'].count().unstack(0).plot.bar(title = 'TITLE', figsize=(14,8))
_ = ax.set_xlabel('day')
_ = ax.set_ylabel('count')
mylabels = ['R', 'L']
_ = ax.legend(labels=mylabels)
plt.show()
```

[image: daily plot]
I tried the following which didn't work (but also didn't throw an error):

```
data['date_for_index'] = data['date']
data = data.set_index('date_for_index')
ax = data.groupby(['pos', data['date'].dt.strftime('')])['date'].count().unstack(0).plot.bar(title = 'TITLE', figsize=(14,8))
_ = ax.set_xlabel('day')
_ = ax.set_ylabel('count')
mylabels = ['R', 'L']
ax.set_xticks(data.index)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
_ = plt.xticks(rotation=90) 
mylabels = ['R', 'L']
_ = ax.legend(labels=mylabels)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's not possible to use `matplotlib.dates` tickers with pandas bar plots, because they use entirely different units. You can (a) create a matplotlib bar plot and use the matplotlib.dates tickers, (b) Set the xticks manually for the pandas bar plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I ended up doing it:

```
grouped_data = data \
.groupby(['pos', data['date'].dt.strftime('')])['date'] \
.count() \
.unstack(0) \
.reset_index()
grouped_data.columns = ['date', 'r_count', 'l_count']
grouped_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(grouped_data['date'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 8))
ax.bar(grouped_data['date'], grouped_data['r_count'])
ax.bar(grouped_data['date'], grouped_data['l_count'])
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.set_xlabel('date')
ax.set_ylabel('count')
mylabels = ['r', 'l']
ax.legend(labels=mylabels)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]