# Datetime Stacked Bar Chart with Matplotlib from dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Background:**

I am stuck. I'm like a deer looking at headlights.

I've queried the following dataframe from MySQL table.

```
date          operation
2020-05-07        A
2020-05-08        B
2020-05-08        A
2020-05-12        A
2020-05-12        A
2020-05-12        B
2020-05-13        C
2020-05-13        A
2020-05-13        B
2020-05-14        A
2020-05-19        B
2020-05-21        A
2020-05-25        A
2020-05-26        B
2020-05-26        C
2020-05-26        A
2020-05-26        A
2020-05-29        A
```

I have no idea how to make it a stacked bar chart with matplotlib.

**Research:**

1. [Grouped Bar-Chart with customized DateTime Index using pandas and Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330786/grouped-bar-chart-with-customized-datetime-index-using-pandas-and-matplotlib)
2. [Stacked bar plot using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44309507/stacked-bar-plot-using-matplotlib)

**Question:**

How can I generate a stack-bar-chart with matplot lib with the above sample data?

**Code snippet:**

```
import datetime as dt
import mysql.connector
import os
import pandas as pd
# import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

def generate_monthly_graph():
    query = "SELECT [...]`"
    mycursor.execute(query)
    mycursor.execute(query)
    data = mycursor.fetchall()

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'operation'])
    
    df = df.set_index('date')

    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `crosstab` then `plot.bar`:

```
# convert to date, no need for set_index
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

pd.crosstab(df.date,df.operation).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

If you want monthly, you can use `dt.to_period('M')` to get monthly dates and `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df.date.dt.to_period('M'),df.operation).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output (for the sample data):

[image]

---

**Update** to have all the dates on the x-axis:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

mindate, maxdate = df['date'].agg(['min','max'])

all_dates = pd.date_range(mindate, maxdate, freq='D').date

(pd.crosstab(df.date,df.operation)
   .reindex(all_dates)
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: with the daily one, how can I make it so everyday is shown in the x-axis, ie define the x limits `plt.xlim(datetime.date(2020, 5, 1), datetime.date(2020, 5, 31))` also, with this graph, my dates are appearing to be `00:00`

Comment: You can use [DayLocator](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/71850/matplotlib.dates.DayLocator).

Comment: I'm struggling :( Any chance you could kindly update your answer and _write_ the whole code? Where one can define the title, x and y axis [custom] labels? please?

Comment: what about custom range like `datetime.date(2020, 5, 1), datetime.date(2020, 5, 31))` mentioned in my first comment

Comment: Replace `mindate` with ''2020-05-01'` and `maxdate` with `'2020-05-31'` in the definition of `all_dates`.

Comment: still struggling with some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205274/matplotlib-dataframe-2-column-dates-non-numerical-data-stacked-bar-chart-defi)

Comment: Any help please?