# matplotlib dataframe month overview of 2 datasets [dates, non-numerical-data] stacked bar chart defining attributes

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Background:**

I have managed to create the following graph, but I have difficulty with some of the elements

**For What It's Worth:**

The graph will eventually have 12 months of data (ie 12 bars), as the database grows. The point of this chart is to give a month-to-month comparative overview of the operations A, B and C.

**Disclaimer:**

This graph below is what I want to achieve, however I would like integrate my questions into the graph ***If there is an alternative to obtaining a stacked graph with all the dates, please free to share the code with me***.

[image]

*... and after 2 months of data the output will be*

[image]

**Question:**

How can I define the following:

- Make the `y-axis` integers
- Change the `date format` (to `%m %Y` ) of the `x-axis`
- Define the chart size (`400 by 800`) (it's a little small as I think the dates are getting cut off)
- Add a `this is my chart` title to the chart
- Add labels (`this is x axis`, `this is y-axis`) to the x & y axis ?

**MWE:**

```
import datetime as dt
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

mycursor.execute(query)
data = mycursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'Operation'])

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
pd.crosstab(df.date.dt.to_period('M'),df.Operation).plot.bar(stacked=True, color=COLOR_LIST)

today = dt.date.today()
filename = "\\annual_{}.png".format(today.strftime("%b_%Y")).lower()
plt.savefig(CURRENT_DIRECTORY + filename)
print("\n\nGenerated: {}".format(CURRENT_DIRECTORY + filename))
```

**Data set:**

`print(df)` yields the following:

```
date          Operation
2020-05-07        A
2020-05-08        B
2020-05-08        A
2020-05-12        A
2020-05-12        A
2020-05-12        B
2020-05-13        C
2020-05-13        A
2020-05-13        B
2020-05-14        A
2020-05-19        B
2020-05-21        A
2020-05-25        A
2020-05-26        B
2020-05-26        C
2020-05-26        A
2020-05-26        A
2020-05-29        A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added data for June and drew a graph; customization of the date display on the x-axis is automatically set I wanted to do this, but it didn't work, so I created a display string and set it up.

```
import datetime as dt
# import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import datetime
COLOR_LIST = ['red','blue','orange']
# mycursor.execute(query)
# data = mycursor.fetchall()
data ='''
date Operation
2020-05-07 A
2020-05-08 B
2020-05-08 A
2020-05-12 A
2020-05-12 A
2020-05-12 B
2020-05-13 C
2020-05-13 A
2020-05-13 B
2020-05-14 A
2020-05-19 B
2020-05-21 A
2020-05-25 A
2020-05-26 B
2020-05-26 C
2020-05-26 A
2020-05-26 A
2020-05-29 A
2020-05-30 B
2020-05-31 C
2020-06-01 A
2020-06-02 A
2020-06-03 C
2020-06-04 B
2020-06-05 C
2020-06-06 C
2020-06-07 A
2020-06-08 A
2020-06-09 C
'''
# df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['date', 'Operation'])
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
ax = pd.crosstab(df.date.dt.to_period('M'),df.Operation).plot.bar(stacked=True, color=COLOR_LIST)

today = dt.date.today()

# Define the chart size (400 by 800)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,8), dpi=100) 
# Add a this is my chart title to the chart
ax.set_title('this is my chart') 
# Add labels (this is x axis, this is y-axis)
ax.set_xlabel('this is x-axis') 
ax.set_ylabel('this is y-axis')
# Make the y-axis integers(by 2 interval)
start, end = ax.get_ylim()
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(start, end, 2))
# Change the date format (to %m %Y ) of the x-axis
labels = ['05 20', '06 20']
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(labels))

# filename = "\\annual_{}.png".format(today.strftime("%b_%Y")).lower()
# plt.savefig(CURRENT_DIRECTORY + filename)
# print("\n\nGenerated: {}".format(CURRENT_DIRECTORY + filename))
```

[image]