# plot only the time from datetime objects in matplot lib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a list of date and time values with the format `'2019-08-24 08:57:18.550'` for example. I have successfully converted them into numbers that matplotlib understands using `datetime` with the code `matplotlib.dates.date2num(points)` however I am having trouble getting matplotlib to plot only the time, not the associated date. 
The graph it creates has tick marks with labels such as `08-24 12` which I assume has the format "month-date hour". I would like it to only plot the time, ideally with the format "hour:minute" or something along those lines. How do I get matplotlib to do this?

Comment: Feed in the dates as your have them, but create a custom date formatter for the axis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33746112/1552748

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, and it is the current date/time that you are looking for, then:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> current_time = datetime.now()
>>> current_time
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 18, 22, 4, 41, 425538)

#################(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond)
```

You can then format it (this is what I didn't quite understand what you were asking), but if you wanted hour:minute format then:

```
from datetime import datetime

time = datetime.now()

hour = time.hour
minute = time.minute

print(f"{hour}:{minute}")
```

You should note that `datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 18, 22, 4, 41, 425538)` was not iterable.

Comment: How would I get matplotlib to label the tick marks on the graph using that format? The way it is labeling points on the graph is `08-24 12`, but I don't want the date to show up in the labels. So if the time of a given point was 12:10 (so hour is 12, minute is 10) then I want the label on the graph to be  `12:10`, without the date. Sorry if the post was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the format that you need to add to your code to set the x axis with 7:00 time format.

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timezone

# Define the date format
date_form = DateFormatter("%H:%M")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
```

If you want to show secconds just add :%S