# How to calculate monthly annual average from daily dataframe and plot it by abbreviated month

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have daily values of precipitation and temperature for a period of several years. I would like to compute the average of the precipitation and temperature for each month of the year (January to December). For precipitation I first need to calculate the summation of daily precipitation for each month, and then compute the average for the same month for all the years of data. For temperature I need to average the monthly averages of the values (so an average of all the data for all the months gives the exact same result). Once this is done I need to plot both sets of data (precipitation and temperature) using abbreviated months.

I cannot find a way to compute the precipitation values and to be able to obtain the sum for each month and to then average it for all years. Furthermore, I am having trouble to display the format in abbreviated months.

This is what I have tried so far (unsuccessfully):

```
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

example = [['01.10.1965 00:00', 13.88099957,    5.375],
    ['02.10.1965 00:00',    5.802999973,    3.154999971],
    ['03.10.1965 00:00',    9.605699539,    0.564999998],
    ['14.10.1965 00:00',    0.410299987,    1.11500001],
    ['31.10.1965 00:00',    6.184500217,    -0.935000002],
    ['01.11.1965 00:00',    0.347299993,    -5.235000134],
    ['02.11.1965 00:00',    0.158299997,    -8.244999886],
    ['03.11.1965 00:00',    1.626199961,    -3.980000019],
    ['24.10.1966 00:00',    0,              3.88499999],
    ['25.10.1966 00:00',    0.055100001,    1.279999971],
    ['30.10.1966 00:00',    0.25940001,     -5.554999828]]

names = ["date","Pobs","Tobs"]
data = pd.DataFrame(example, columns=names)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

#I think the average of temperature is well computed but the precipitation would give the complete summation for all years!
tempT = data.groupby([data['date'].dt.month_name()], sort=False).mean().eval('Tobs')
tempP = data.groupby([data['date'].dt.month_name()], sort=False).sum().eval('Pobs') 

fig = plt.figure(); ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1); ax2 = ax1.twinx();
ax1.bar(tempP.index.tolist(), tempP.values, color='blue')
ax2.plot(tempT.index.tolist(), tempT.values, color='red')
ax1.set_ylabel('Precipitation [mm]', fontsize=10)
ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature [°C]', fontsize=10) 
#ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b")) #this line does not work properly!
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working code for your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

example = [['01.10.1965 00:00',13.88099957,5.375], ...]

names = ["date","Pobs","Tobs"]
data = pd.DataFrame(example, columns=names)
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')

# Temperature:
tempT = data.groupby([data['date'].dt.month_name()], sort=False).mean().eval('Tobs')

# Precipitation:
df_sum = data.groupby([data['date'].dt.month_name(), data['date'].dt.year], sort=False).sum()  # get sum for each individual month
df_sum.index.rename(['month','year'], inplace=True)  # just renaming the index
df_sum.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)  # make the month-index to a column
tempP = df_sum.groupby([df_sum['month']], sort=False).mean().eval('Pobs')  # get mean over all years

fig = plt.figure();
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1);
ax2 = ax1.twinx();

xticks = pd.to_datetime(tempP.index.tolist(), format='%B').sort_values() # must work for both axes
ax1.bar(xticks, tempP.values, color='blue')
ax2.plot(xticks, tempT.values, color='red')
plt.xticks(pd.to_datetime(tempP.index.tolist(), format='%B').sort_values()) # to show all ticks

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%b")) # must be called after plotting both axes

ax1.set_ylabel('Precipitation [mm]', fontsize=10)
ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature [°C]', fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

Explanation:
[As of this StackOverflow answer, DateFormatter uses mdates.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33746112/3692004)
For this to work, **you need to make a DatetimeIndex-Array** from the month names, which the DateFormatter can then re-format.

As for the calculation, I understood the solution to your problem as such that we take the **sum within each individual month and then take the average of these sums over all years**. This leaves you with the average total precipitation per month over all years.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! I didn't realize that you could add the second groupby for 'years', but that's great to know. It makes things much easier to compute from there on.