# Using matplotlib, how to plot a bar chart and not show dates in between date index values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a dataframe

[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
ax.bar(df_temp.index, df_temp['Client $ Amt'].cumsum()/100000)
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])
```

[image]

The problem is the graph is showing the empty dates in between the index of my graph. I want to not show those though.

I have already done

```
df_temp.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

But the dates in the x-axis are in long format and I am not able to add the line

```
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])
```

where I collapse the dates. I need to collapse the dates otherwise the x-axis ticks become unreadable when I add more dates to the dataframe.

I am looking for either one of two solutions. Not show in-between dates in the figure plot, or combine dates and show in a shorter format in the df.plot() example.

**Edit**
Here is the json dump of the dataframe. You can load it with `df_temp_new = pd.read_json(json_dict)`

'{"Client $ Amt":{"1483401600000":20,"1483488000000":-20.4,"1483574400000":20.76,"1483920000000":79.5684759707,"1484006400000":20.123,"1484179200000":20.654,"1484265600000":-20.876,"1484611200000":203.1234,"1484697600000":20.654,"1484784000000":20.432,"1484870400000":204.432,"1485129600000":-20.543,"1485216000000":20.654,"1485388800000":108.106,"1485475200000":2151.18,"1485734400000":1515.12,"1485820800000":102.327,"1485907200000":573.41,"1486080000000":449.65,"1486339200000":48.9152,"1486684800000":268.7302,"1486944000000":415.744,"1487030400000":22.335167,"1487116800000":20.6546,"1487203200000":865.45,"1487635200000":43.23,"1487721600000":543.234,"1488153600000":154.476,"1488240000000":20,"1488326400000":20,"1488412800000":20,"1488499200000":280.17256}}'

Comment: can you export the df_temp to something we can load? Perhaps also post the json-dump

Comment: @MaartenFabré just added it. Should be easy to load now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a post explaining how to handle this [Pandas bar plot changes date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format).

The code that worked for me is

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ax = (df_temp.cumsum()).plot(kind='bar')

ticklabels = ['']*len(df_temp.index)

# Every 4th ticklable shows the month and day
ticklabels[::4] = [item.strftime('%b %d') for item in df_temp.index[::4]]

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in an `axis` to the pandas plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
df_temp.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
```

So you can use all the matplotlib sorcery afterwards

Comment: I gave it a shot but `ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])` has no effect. I still see every date on the x-axis.