# Matplotlib bar plot with dates - xaxis format

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib, formatting

I am trying to improve the x-axis format on a bar chart of a time series with a lot of data.
By default Matplotlib adds a date label for each data, looking like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

AAPL = pdr.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo', "2020-01-01")["Adj Close"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
AAPL.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(15,6), grid=True, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I also tried Matplotlib.dates (mdates) and then add format (year-month) and got a better display, but the problem arose that the date values ​​are changed to the year 1970.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
AAPL.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(15,6), grid=True, ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Greetings and thanks

Comment: Hi, can you please share some data?

Comment: The data used is automatically downloaded with this command  AAPL = pdr.DataReader("AAPL", 'yahoo', "2020-01-01")["Adj Close"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib fix axis - too many dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090043/matplotlib-fix-axis-too-many-dates)

Comment: You need to convert the dates to datetime objects.

Comment: Thank you Jody. But the DF.index is dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=491, freq=None

Comment: good answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965026/why-is-my-date-axis-formatting-broken-when-plotting-with-pandas-built-in-plot-c