# How do I make my x labels increment in months?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn

So I have this dataframe: [image: img]

And I want to create a graph with the xlabels corresponding with the months the records are in. I've tried:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date')
l = sns.lineplot(x=df.index,y='Appliances',data=df, sort=False, color='grey')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
# Set the locator
locator = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month
# Specify the format - %b gives us Jan, Feb...
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
X = plt.gca().xaxis
X.set_major_locator(locator)
X.set_major_formatter(fmt)
plt.show()
```

which gives me:
[image]

As you can see, the xlabels are not showing.. I'm not sure why.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format)

Comment: What happens if you just use 10 lines of the dataframe?

Comment: A [mcve] would allow to find out why this doesn't work. Also see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: `df.set_index('date')` this returns a new dataframe without changing `df`. The dataframe is still indexed by integer so your date formatter has no effect. Change it to either `df = df.set_index('date')` or `df.set_index('date', inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, I figured out the problem was that i didnt set the new dataframe to have a changed index:

```
df = df.set_index('date')
```