# Pandas df histo, format my x ticker and include empty

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, group-by, ticker

I got this pandas df:

```
index      TIME
12:07      2019-06-03  12:07:28
10:04      2019-06-04  10:04:25
11:14      2019-06-09  11:14:25
...
```

I use this command to do an histogram to plot how much occurence for each 15min periods

```
df['TIME'].groupby([df["TIME"].dt.hour, df["TIME"].dt.minute]).count().plot(kind="bar")
```

my plot look like this:

[image]

How can I get x tick like 10:15 in lieu of (10, 15) and how manage to add x tick missing like 9:15, 9:30... to get a complet time line??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) your `TIME` column to 15 mins intervalls and count the number of rows. Then plot a regular bar chart.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TIME': pd.to_datetime('2019-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(pd.np.random.rand(100) * 3, unit='h')})
df = df[df.TIME.dt.minute > 15] # make gap

ax = df.resample('15T', on='TIME').count().plot.bar(rot=0)
ticklabels = [x.get_text()[-8:-3] for x in ax.get_xticklabels()]
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatter(ticklabels))
```

(for details about formatting datetime ticklabels of pandas bar plots see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format))

[image]

Comment: Your exemple work well but I dont know why it don't work on my data... but the idea is on your exemple, I will find the bug in my method. Thank for your help!