# the xtick label of python matplotlib bar plot is over crowding, how to make xticks sparse

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I want plot a bar plot using the following code

```
num_trade.plot.bar()
```

where `num_trade` is a `pandas.Series` object. This is the result

[image]

the xtick labels are crowded, how can make it more sparse to make the labels more visible?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the x-axis is time series data, an easy way to achieve this is to use the following settings, which will take care of it automatically

```
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Comment: what is mdates?

Comment: import matplotlib.dates as mdates
[Matplotlib date format](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter)