# Matplotlib Line vs. Bar plot DateTime axis formatting

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, xticks

I have a DataFrame with a DateTime index:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randrange
dates = pd.date_range(start="2020-02-01",end='2020-04-18',freq='1d')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=dates,data=[randrange(10000) for i in range(78)]
```

Now when I plot the data as a line plot, matplotlib produces a nicely formatted x axis:

```
df.plot(figsize=(12,4))
```

[image: line plot]

However, if instead I do a bar plot, I now get something quite horrible:

```
df.plot(kind='bar',figsize=(12,4)),
```

[image: bar plot]

This is quite disconcerting, as it is the same DataFrame. 
What I want is to have the bar plot, but with the nicely formatted DateTime axis.

Is there an easy way to achieve that?
I tried using the bar command directly, but that produces yet another x axis format, not as nice as the one generated by plotting with a pandas method.

Comment: This should help you :https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/date_index_formatter.html

Comment: @Rajat: Thanks. Yes, I understand that I can manually pick a DateTime format. There are two problems with this: First, it requires a lot of work. Second, how would I generate the same nice format that I get with the line plot?

Comment: Is there a way to take the axis generated by the line plot and re-use it for the bar plot? I tried doing that (by copying locations and formats from xticks), but I was not successful. I think the reason is that the ticks structure for the bar plot is different than the line plot.

Comment: May be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
In [23]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 12))
Attribute Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling must be set before QCoreApplication is created.

In [27]: ax.bar(df.index.values,
    ...:        df[0],
    ...:        color='purple')
Out[27]: <BarContainer object of 78 artists>

In [29]: import matplotlib.dates as mdates
    ...: from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

In [30]: date_form = DateFormatter("%m-%d")
    ...: ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
    ...:
    ...: # Ensure a major tick for each week using (interval=1)
    ...: ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1))
    ...: plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is about how far I got as well. It's still not as nice as the one from the line plot...