# Pandas Dataframe.plot, how to change x-axis labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot on a bar graph a year long set of values with Python/Pandas. The resulting graph is quite cluttered and my attempts to set xtick labels are not working.

My original code:

```
import datetime as dt
import random
import pandas as pd

#generate year-long list of dates
i = 0
list_of_dates = []
last_date = dt.date(2017, 1, 1)
while i < 365:
    list_of_dates.append(last_date)
    last_date += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    #print(last_date)
    i = i + 1

#generate random values for example
daily_rainfall = []
j = 0
while j < 365:
    daily_rainfall.append(random.randint(0,3))
    j = j + 1
    
#put lists in DF
rainfall_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list_of_dates, daily_rainfall)),columns=["Date","Precipitation"])
rainfall_dataframe = rainfall_dataframe.groupby(["Date"]).sum()

rainfall_dataframe.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(13,7))
```

returns this:

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yKGY.jpg)

Unusable, obviously. So I wanted it to only label x-ticks on a monthly basis. I tried creating a list of datetime date objects that was only the first of every month but when I try to pass this to df.plot() it returns nothing.

```
xlablist = []
xlablist.append(dt.date(2017, 1, 1))
xlablist.append(dt.date(2017, 6, 1))
xlablist.append(dt.date(2018, 1, 1))

rainfall_dataframe.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(13,7), xticks=xlablist)
```

returns:

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlKAE.jpg)

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas bar plot changes date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solutions, using *MonthLocator* to specify where to
put *x* labels and *DateFormatter* to specify the format of labels:

```
# Imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Create source data
np.random.seed(0)
dates = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', end='2017-12-31')
rainfall = np.random.randint(0, 20, dates.size)

# Drawing
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('mm')
plt.title('Rainfall 2017')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b %Y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
ax.bar(dates, rainfall)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=30);
```

For the above source data I got the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Date locators](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers).

```py
import datetime as dt
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


#generate year-long list of dates
i = 0
list_of_dates = []
last_date = dt.date(2017, 1, 1)
while i < 365:
    list_of_dates.append(last_date)
    last_date += dt.timedelta(days=1)
    #print(last_date)
    i = i + 1

#generate random values for example
daily_rainfall = []
j = 0
while j < 365:
    daily_rainfall.append(random.randint(0,3))
    j = j + 1
    
#put lists in DF
rainfall_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list_of_dates, daily_rainfall)),columns=["Date","Precipitation"])
rainfall_dataframe = rainfall_dataframe.groupby(["Date"]).sum()

rainfall_dataframe.plot(kind="bar", figsize=(13,7))

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())

plt.xticks(rotation=45)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I tried running your code exactly in a fresh Jupyter Notebook and the xticks didn't show up. Is there a problem with my install of matplotlib or something?

Comment: I don't use Jupyter Notebook. Does it work on your Python IDLE?

Comment: @Krbin Does this official demo: [Date tick labels](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html?highlight=monthlocator) work in your Jupyter Notebook?