# Get timestamps between two timestamp type columns , explode and plot as a shaded area between the given timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Here is what my dataframe looks like:
Switch|  start|                   end    |

```
OFF |2021-11-14 16:00:22    |2021-11-14 16:00:46
OFF |2021-11-14 16:01:19    |2021-11-14 16:01:42
ON  |2021-11-14 16:02:13    |2021-11-14 16:02:37
ON  |2021-11-14 16:03:15    |2021-11-14 16:03:35    
ON  |2021-11-14 16:04:41    |2021-11-14 16:04:54    
OFF |2021-11-14 16:04:04    |2021-11-14 16:04:16    
ON  |2021-11-14 16:11:07    |2021-11-14 16:11:16
```

I want to plot this using matplotlib or seaborn something like here [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75713768/plot-shaded-area-between-two-points-in-time) where  I want to display the shaded regions as in [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5KcT.png)
but I also want two different colors for ON and off.
How do I do this using Pandas and Seaborn?

Expected output will have:
Timestamps on x axis and y axis will have a lineplot using code like this

`y_values = np.random.rand(20)`

`x_values = pd.date_range("2023-11-14T16:00:00", "2023-11-14T16:12:00", 20)`

`plt.plot(x_values, y_values)`

And then I want shaded regions using the dataframe shown above to show different positions of the switch
[image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIsh8.png)

I tried exploding and unnesting like in SQL but having a hard time.

Comment: What does your output plot look like for this dataset?

Comment: Added a plot link. You wull see a grade shaded region, I want to add such shaded areas with two colors , one for ON and one for OFF. @SurajShourie

Comment: What did you try? What is on your x-axis and y-axis of the plot that you want? you only have datetime values