# Datetime indexing in Pandas plots

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, indexing

I'm trying to make a time series plot, using Pandas and matplotlib, with ticked weekdays (Monday) on x axis. However, I've encountered a strange behavior which I believe is caused by (wrong?) handling of datetime indexing in `pandas.Series.plot` function.

From the documentation for [`pandas.Series.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) (also in [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)):

- `use_index` **bool**, default `True`.
  Use index as ticks for x axis.

However, although the index is of `DatetimeIndex` type, it looks like it is not considered as such (probably handled as string?).

Consider the following code which tries to create the same plot using three different approaches:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl


idx = pd.date_range(start='2020-10-02', periods=35)
Y = np.cumsum(np.random.uniform(0, 10, idx.size))

ts = pd.Series(Y, idx)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6), nrows=3, constrained_layout=True)

ts.plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[0]) # use_index=True is used by defualt
axes[0].xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.dates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1, byweekday=mpl.dates.MONDAY))

ts.plot(kind='bar', ax=axes[1])
axes[1].xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.dates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1, byweekday=mpl.dates.MONDAY))
axes[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))

axes[2].bar(ts.index, ts.values)
axes[2].xaxis.set_major_locator(mpl.dates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1, byweekday=mpl.dates.MONDAY))
axes[2].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

The results is
[image]

I expected all three plots would be more-or-less the same. And they are, excluding the ticks of x axis (which should mark Monday's dates). As i see it, the `DatetimeIndex` is not really recognized correctly in `pandas.Series.plot`. The dates on the first plot are correct, but the ticked dates are not Mondays. What is even more annoying, if a new format is applied on the ticks (second plot) even the dates are wrong!

The behavior of `bar(ts.index, ts.values)` is correct and marks Mondays as expected.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30135182/9245853) discusses the issue you are seeing in the second subplot.

Comment: Can you post versions of the packages?  I do not get the same plot from your code

Comment: Hi @Tom, I've now tried the code on my home PC and it does look different than the one above: It doesn't have any ticks whatsoever in first two subplots! Also very strange... The versions are:`pd.__version__  '0.25.3' mpl.__version__ '3.0.2'`. Initial problem occurred on relatively new Anaconda installation (approx. a month ago), I'll check the versions tomorrow.

Comment: @Tom the versions for which original issue is encountered: `pd.__version__  '1.1.3' mpl.__version__ '3.3.1'`