# Trim and Format Date Axis Formatting for Dataframe in HeatMap

Tags: dataframe, plot, date-format

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(113, 3), columns = ["116", "118", "120"])

dates = pd.date_range(start = pd.to_datetime("today"), periods = 113, freq = "D")
df.index = dates

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt="g", cmap='coolwarm', cbar_kws={"shrink": 0.9}, 
        annot_kws={'size': 'x-small', 'alpha': 0.8}                           
        )
```

From this code, I would like to format the date shown on the heapmap.  I would like to display just the date without time and ideally show a date every 3-4 tick marks.  The default output looks like "2023-11-26T12:42:43.934334343433".

I have been through the post below and several others and haven't been able to find something that works.  I could reformat the dates at one point but the tick marks were not matching up or correct.

[Pandas bar plot changes date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format)

With a smaller set of data, like 10 data points the following works:

```
ax.set_yticklabels([x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for x in df.index])
```

But with 113 datapoints, I get this:

ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (29), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of labels (113).

There are too many datapoints so a limited number of ticks are being shown, but now sure how to tell how many ticks there are or just format what's there.