Wrong axis data when ploting panda dataframe
I have the following dataframe:




date
new
todo
fixed
close




0
2023-08-20 00:00:00+00:00
2
0
0
0


1
2023-08-27 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


2
2023-09-03 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


3
2023-09-10 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


4
2023-09-17 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


5
2023-09-24 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


6
2023-10-01 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


7
2023-10-08 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


8
2023-10-15 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


9
2023-10-22 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


10
2023-10-29 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
5


11
2023-11-05 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
3


12
2023-11-12 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
3


13
2023-11-19 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
1


14
2023-11-26 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
1


15
2023-12-03 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
1


16
2023-12-10 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


17
2023-12-17 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
1


18
2023-12-24 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
3


19
2023-12-31 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


20
2024-01-07 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


21
2024-01-14 00:00:00+00:00
0
1
1
0


22
2024-01-21 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


23
2024-01-28 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


24
2024-02-04 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
1


25
2024-02-11 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


26
2024-02-18 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


27
2024-02-25 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


28
2024-03-03 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


29
2024-03-10 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
1
0


30
2024-03-17 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


31
2024-03-24 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


32
2024-03-31 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
0


33
2024-04-07 00:00:00+00:00
0
0
0
1



Date columns is filled with Timestamp objects
I try to to plot the dataframe but I have the result below. Bar seems OK but axis are incorrect, I have date around 1970 instead of 2024.

Any clue on the problem?
Here is the code I used:
    matplotlib.use('agg')
    matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10))

    df.plot(
        kind='bar',
        ax=ax,
        x='date',
        use_index=True,
        stacked=True,
    )

    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.AutoDateFormatter(ax.xaxis.get_major_locator()))

    ax.tick_params(
        'x',
        labelrotation=75
    )

    ax.figure.savefig(f'fig/{filename}')

    plt.close(ax.figure)

EDIT:
I did some trial on @BigBen suggestion.
using directly matplotlib seems working:
ax.bar(df['date'],
    df['CLOSED'],
    width=3,
    )


so it seems to come from pandas formater

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30133280/pandas-bar-plot-changes-date-format

Thanks @BigBen for your comment, it seems totally related to the formatter and if I remove the line ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter it is perfectly OK

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('agg')
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')
                
raw_data = [["2023-08-20 00:00:00+00:00",   2,  0,  0,  0],
            ["2023-08-27 00:00:00+00:00",   0,  1,  0,  0],
            ["2023-09-03 00:00:00+00:00",   0,  0,  3,  0],
            ["2023-09-10 00:00:00+00:00",   0,  0,  0,  4]]

date, new, todo, fixed, lose  = list(map(list, zip(*raw_data)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"date":date, "new":new, "todo":todo, "fixed":fixed, "lose":lose})


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10))
df.plot(
    kind='bar',
    ax=ax,
    x="date",
    use_index=True,
    stacked=True,
)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
ax.figure.savefig(f'fig/{filename}')
plt.close(ax.figure)


Without time:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('agg')
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot') 
               
raw_data = [["2023-08-20 00:00:00+00:00",   2,  0,  0,  0],
            ["2023-08-27 00:00:00+00:00",   0,  1,  0,  0],
            ["2023-09-03 00:00:00+00:00",   0,  0,  3,  0],
            ["2023-09-10 00:00:00+00:00",   0,  0,  0,  4]]
date, new, todo, fixed, lose  = list(map(list, zip(*raw_data)))
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"date":date, "new":new, "todo":todo, "fixed":fixed, "lose":lose})
df.date = [d.split(" ")[0] for d in date]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 10))
df.plot(
    kind='bar',
    ax=ax,
    x="date",
    use_index=True,
    stacked=True,
)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
ax.figure.savefig(f'fig/{filename}')
plt.close(ax.figure)



Hello @BigBen,
Thank you for your comment, I've updated my answer to exclude time.
