# Pandas plot bar chart over line

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a bar and a line on the same graph. Here is what works and what does not work. Would anyone please explain why?

What does NOT work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2001,2002,2003,2004,2005], 'value':[100,200,300,400,500]})
df['value1']= df['value']*0.4
df['value2'] = df['value']*0.6
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,8))
df.plot(x = ['year'], y = ['value'], kind = 'line', ax = ax)
df.plot(x = ['year'], y= ['value1','value2'], kind = 'bar', ax = ax)
```

[image]

But somehow it works when I delete the `x=['year']` in the first plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,8))
df.plot(y = ['value'], kind = 'line', ax = ax)
df.plot(x = ['year'], y= ['value1','value2'], kind = 'bar', ax = ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas plot does not overlay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948576/pandas-plot-does-not-overlay)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42813890/python-making-combined-bar-and-line-plot-with-secondary-y-axis) might be of interest as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue is that `kinds="bar"` plots the bars on the low end of the x-axis, (so 2001 is actually on 0) while `kind="line"` plots it according to the value given. Removing the `x=["year"]` just made it plot the value according to the order (which by luck matches your data precisely).

There might be a better way, but the quickest way I know would be to stop considering the year to be a number.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2001,2002,2003,2004,2005], 'value':[100,200,300,400,500]})
df['value1']= df['value']*0.4
df['value2'] = df['value']*0.6
df['year'] = df['year'].astype("string") # Let them be strings!
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,8))
df.plot(x = ['year'], y = ['value'], kind = 'line', ax = ax)
df.plot(x = ['year'], y= ['value1','value2'], kind = 'bar', ax = ax)
```

Treating the year this way makes sense since you treat the year as a categorical data anyway, and the alphabetic order matches the numerical order.

[image]

Comment: I had the sense that I only got it work BY LUCK as well and that's why I posted the question. The explanation is clear and the solution solves my problem in several related issues in my task. Thanks!