# How to overlay plot multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, overlay, boxplot

I've got an excel file containing multiple samples showing output values over a temperature range.  Here's an example:
[SampleData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44v33.gif)

I want to plot Column A as the common x-axis and Columns B,C,D etc. as y-axis values overlaid with boxplots. It should look like this. [Output Required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCkS6.gif)

So far I've imported the data into a pandas dataframe but I'm having difficulty creating an overlay plot from the df in a loop as I dont know what to set the 'y' value to below.  Here's my code:

```
dfthermog = pd.read_csv("Thermog.csv")

dfthermog = dfthermog.set_index('Temperature')

for col_name, data in dfthermog.items():

    dfthermog.plot(x ='Temperature', y='**???**', kind = 'line')
```

Is a loop and using a df the best way to handle this?
Can I have and index label for the Sample ID also (top row)?
Any advice how to do this would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try if this answer is helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42951077/14919627

Comment: Thanks.  This provides some pointers but its not the efficient way that I am looking for due to the large number of Sample data that I need to overlay.  I've added a target image plot to show what I am trying to achieve.