# Bar format (kind) is not displaying the right plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, apache-axis

I need to do a plot using three variables. One of them should be on the secondary Y axis in `bar` format (kind), the remaining variables (two) should be on the left axis using a simple line. However, I got the following chart:

[image]

When I use the three variables in `line` format I get the right plot (which is not very useful for a visual analysis):
[image]

I did a quick test using a small sample from my data (code below). I get the right pic when I use `bar` format for the third one. [image]

I wonder, what is going on? Is there a problem with the data size (which I dont think so bcs I get less than 100 rows)?

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ind':[120.29, 125.45, 127.37, 130.39, 128.30], 
                    'var1':[129.907990, 129.571185, 129.234380, 128.897574, 128.560769], 
                    'var2':[-0.074037, -0.031806, -0.014426, 0.011578, -0.002028]})

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df2['ind'].plot(ax=ax1)
df2['var1'].plot(ax=ax1)
df2['var2'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, color='r')
plt.show()
```

PD: In addition, I noted that in the third pic the line is behind the bar. How can I change that?

Comment: A pandas bar plot is a categorical plot; you get one tick and label per bar. I suppose you can google for something like "pandas plot line and bar in same chart" or so to find an appropriate duplicate Q&A.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior shown, can you post the code you used to create the first plot?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this (this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457861/pandas-dataframe-how-to-mix-bar-and-line-plots-with-different-scales) helped me a lot ). Basically, it is based on the index you set up previously.

This is the new code:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.plot(df2.index, df2['ind']) 
ax1.plot(df2.index, df2['var1'])
ax2.bar(df2.index, df2['var2'], color='r')
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps.