# Combine bar and line chart with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I'm trying to combine a bar chart and a line chart but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482201/plot-pandas-dataframe-as-bar-and-line-on-the-same-one-chart) but to no reveil. I have the following code and Dataframe:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

%matplotlib inline

dates = pd.date_range('2017-09-16',periods=11)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Elektra_Cost': pd.Series([1.483393,                                                
                                           1.483393,
                                           1.483393,
                                           1.481280,
                                           1.470714,
                                           1.470714,
                                           1.470714,
                                           1.506829,
                                           1.677233,
                                           1.721489,
                                           1.766318], index=dates, dtype='float64'), 
                'Gas_Cost': pd.Series([0.82122857, 
                                        0.82122857, 
                                        0.82122857, 
                                        0.85281429, 
                                        1.01074286, 
                                        1.01074286, 
                                        1.01074286,  
                                        0.92651429,  
                                        1.04047059,  
                                        1.50217941, 
                                        0.58479348],index=dates,dtype='float64'),
                'TG10': pd.Series([10.3, 
                                   11.0,
                                   11.3,
                                   12.0,  
                                   13.0,
                                   13.1,
                                   12.8,
                                   11.1,  
                                   13.5,
                                   14.1,  
                                   13.3],index=dates,dtype='float64'), 
                'TN10': pd.Series([5.8, 
                                   4.3, 
                                   9.0,
                                   7.5, 
                                   8.2,
                                   7.9, 
                                   6.0, 
                                   4.3, 
                                   4.6, 
                                   8.5, 
                                   8.8],index=dates,dtype='float64'), 
                'TX10': pd.Series([15.7,  
                                   17.3,  
                                   15.4,  
                                   17.3,  
                                   18.5,  
                                   19.2,  
                                   20.0,  
                                   18.2,  
                                   20.6,
                                   18.9,  
                                   18.2],index=dates,dtype='float64'),

               })
```

I then try to plot the graph like this:

```
ax = df[['TG10', 'TN10', 'TX10']].plot(figsize=(20,15), linestyle='--', secondary_y=['TG10', 'TN10', 'TX10'])
df[['Elektra_Cost', 'Gas_Cost']].plot(figsize=(20,15), kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Which results in the following graph:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2gGp.png)

Any ideas why I'm not seeing the lines (TG10, TN10 and TX10) in the chart?

I'm running this in jupyter notebook

**Update:**

The first suggested [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941685/how-to-show-a-bar-and-line-graph-on-the-same-plot) did the trick. So I ended up doing this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = df[['Elektra_Cost', 'Gas_Cost']].plot(figsize=(20,15), kind='bar')
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(ax.get_xticks(), df[['TG10','TN10', 'TX10']], marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Which resulted in:

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJss6.jpg)

Comment: Oh, they're there all right. It's just that your scale is off. Your costs are < 2, your T* columns are mostly over 10. Either adjust your scale, or draw in subplots.

Comment: @coldspeed there are 2 y axes so it should be visible. What is the OP missing? If there was one, and values with multiple orders of magnitude difference, that comment makes sense. As it is, I don't see how it is so.

Comment: "What is the OP missing?" A [mcve] of the issue!

Comment: The actual problem is not clear; the example is not verifiable, hence I closed as duplicate of several other questions seeking to plot a bar and a line plot in the same chart with dates. If the question makes it clear in how far the answers to those questions are not helping, it can potentially be reopened.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, it should be more clear now.

Comment: Did you not try any of the linked solutions? At the moment I don't see in how far they would fail here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, missed that. Will try and let you know. thanks

Comment: The linked solutions in the yellow box on top (which also appear next to the question under the headline "Linked").